# Derive Interfaces for WCF Proxy Classes

Tags: c#, wcf, interface, code-generation, proxy-classes

**Problem:**

I have two (or more) classes which are *very similar*: The properties of one class are a subset of the properties of the other class. More specifically, the property names and semantics are equal, but not necessarily their types. However, if the types of a property with the same name differ, these types are again *very similar* (in the same sense).

I want to derive common interfaces for all sets of similar classes so I can use instances of different classes in the same way.

Since my classes have more than 100 properties, I would like to avoid to create the interfaces manually if that is possible by any chance.

The interface should encompass the union of all property sets of all similar classes. (When a property is read, which doesn't exist for the specific object, `null` should be returned. When such an undefined property is set, nothing should happen.) So I guess an interface isn't really appropriate anymore, but rather a wrapper class or something different...

**Context:**

I am using WCF to consume a Web Service (*CreateSalesOrder*). The input message of the service requires an element of the XML schema type *Request_SalesOrder* consisting of children of other XSD types like *Request_Item*, *Request_ShipToLocation*, etc.

The output message carries an element of the schema type *Response_SalesOrder* which has similar child elements of the schema types *Response_Item*, *Response_ShipToLocation*, etc. and some additional elements, e.g. element *PriceTotal* of type *Response_PriceTotal*.

I want to build a UI for consuming the Web Service using ASP.Net MVC. So I have a view rendering a form for creating the sales order. After submitting the Web Service request the form fields have to be updated with the values from the Web Service response message.

The form fields are bound to a view model which accesses the properties of the proxy classes. When the form is submitted the view model has to update an instance of proxy class A, while, in case the form is rendered with the values from the response message, the view model reads from an instance of proxy class B.

Answer (score 0):

i think you are talking of the adpater design pattern, but i don't know how to avoid to write manually the interface : http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adapter_pattern